# The function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ to be $t \rightarrow \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}|tx_i+(1-t)y_i|^p$ attains its maximum value at either $0$ or $1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, maxima-minima

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x,y \in \mathbb R^n~;~x \ne y$. Let $p \in (1, \infty)$. Then, the function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ to be $t \rightarrow \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}|tx_i+(1-t)y_i|^p~$ attains its maximum value at either $0$ or $1$ and nowhere in between.

**Proof  Attempt:**

$\Phi(t) = \sum \limits_{1}^{n} |tx_i+(1-t)y_i|^p = \sum \limits_{1}^{n} [a_i (tx_i+(1-t)y_i) ]^p $

where $a_i=1$ if $(tx_i+(1-t)y_i)$ is positive and $-1$ if negative.

$f$ is a continuous function defined on a compact set and thus it must attain its bounds. The above relation :

$\implies \Phi'(t) = \sum \limits_{1}^{n} p [a_i (tx_i+(1-t)y_i) ]^{p-1} \cdot a_i (x_i-y_i)$

$\implies \Phi''(t) = \sum \limits_{1}^{n} p \cdot (p-1)~ | ~(tx_i+(1-t)y_i) ~|^{p-2} \cdot  (x_i-y_i)^2$

It's clear that $\Phi''(t) > 0 \implies \Phi'(t)$ is an increasing function.

> If we prove that either $(i)~~\Phi'(0) > 0,$ then $\Phi'(t) > 0 ~\forall~ t$ which will imply that $\Phi$ is an increasing function and hence, we can obtain that $\Phi$ obtains its greatest value at $t =1 $.  or we prove that $~(ii)~\Phi'(0) \rightarrow -\infty$ and $- \infty <  \Phi'(1) < 0$, then $\Phi$ attains its greatest  value at $t=0$.

$\Phi'(0) = p \sum \limits_{1}^{n} a_i^p  y_i^{p-1} (x_i-y_i)  $

How do I move forward from here?

Comment: Where did you fins this proof? There is a much simpler proof. If the function is $\phi$ then $\phi (t) <t \phi (1)+(1-t) \phi (0)$ for all $ t \in (0,1)$ so maximum cannot be attained at $t$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you please explain a bit further for your proof

Comment: $t \to t^{p}$ is a strictly convex function on $(0,\infty)$ and so the entire sum is a strictly convex function of $t$. Hence the inequality I stated is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you showed that $\phi'(t)$ is increasing, we have that $\phi$ is a convex function.  Thus, we apply [Jenson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) for $t \in [0,1] $:
$$(1-t)\phi(0)+t\phi(1)> \phi((1-t)*0+t*1)=\phi(t)$$
If $a=\max(\phi(0),\phi(1))$, then we have $a>\phi(t) \forall t \in (0,1)$. Thus, $a$ is the maximum value of $\phi$ which is attained at $t=0$ or $t=1$

Comment: I showed that $\Phi'$ is increasing and not that $\Phi$ is increasing

Comment: @MathMan Sorry that's a typo

Comment: :-thanks. Will accept your answer.